# How to get a text label before a daterangepicker in plotly dash?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

This should be just a matter of putting text in front and making the div inline block or something like that.

Want it to look like "DATE: ". Using html.Div fails and puts things on separate lines even with the DATE inside the 2nd Div.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import re

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='my-date-picker-range',
        min_date_allowed=dt(1995, 8, 5),
        max_date_allowed=dt(2017, 9, 19),
        initial_visible_month=dt(2017, 8, 5),
        end_date=dt(2017, 8, 25).date()
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-range')
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container-date-picker-range', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date')])
def update_output(start_date, end_date):
    string_prefix = 'You have selected: '
    if start_date is not None:
        start_date = dt.strptime(re.split('T| ', start_date)[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
        start_date_string = start_date.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
        string_prefix = string_prefix + 'Start Date: ' + start_date_string + ' | '
    if end_date is not None:
        end_date = dt.strptime(re.split('T| ', end_date)[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
        end_date_string = end_date.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
        string_prefix = string_prefix + 'End Date: ' + end_date_string
    if len(string_prefix) == len('You have selected: '):
        return 'Select a date to see it displayed here'
    else:
        return string_prefix


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Done. I just grabbed one of the examples.

Comment: And you just `python file.py` to run it.

Comment: It's probably simple ... it is just output html but can't figure out for the life of me where you jam things. Probably set an id and css it is what they expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this layout working for you?

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(["DATE: ",
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='my-date-picker-range',
        min_date_allowed=dt(1995, 8, 5),
        max_date_allowed=dt(2017, 9, 19),
        initial_visible_month=dt(2017, 8, 5),
        end_date=dt(2017, 8, 25).date()
    )],
    style={'width': '49%', 'display': 'inline-block'}), 
    html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-range')
])
```

The trick is adding another `Div` with two elements and the `inline-block` style.

Answer (score 0):

stick a label above the date picker and give it width=100%:

```
dbc.Col(
    [
    dbc.Label("Start Date", html_for="start-date", style=dict(width='100%')),
    dcc.DatePickerSingle(
        id='start-date',
        date=datetime.datetime.today().date(),
        clearable=True,
    ),                              
    ],
    width=2
),
```